# Parse Cloud job

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a job in the parse cloud, inside the job I've a Parse.Cloud.run, when I run this function works fine and parse data base is update, but in the in the cloud job statuses appears failed. Here's my code:

Thanks in advance.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateTopsThreeJob", function(request, status) {

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var query = new Parse.Query("_User");

query.descending("followersOfMe");
query.limit(3);

query.find({
    success: function(results) {

        var TestJS   = Parse.Object.extend("testJS");
        var test     = new TestJS();
        var listTops = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 

            var object = results[i].get("username");
            listTops.push(object);

        }

        Parse.Cloud.run("updateTopsThree", {objects: listTops}, {
            success: function(result) {

                status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
                response.success(result)
            },
            error: function(error) {
                status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
            }
        });

        response.success(listTops);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error("failed");
    }
});    
});

Parse.Cloud.define("updateTopsThree", function(request, response) {
var tops = Parse.Object.extend("testJS");
var query = new Parse.Query(tops);

query.get(ObjIDs.topsThreeID(), {
    success: function(topsThree) {

        topsThree.set("topsThree", request.params.objects);
        topsThree.save();

        response.success(topsThree);
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
        response.error(error);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Parse Cloud Code runs much like any other javascript file.  In order to declare another function to be called within the parse .js file, such as in this case, you do not need to define the function using Parse syntax. Define and call it just as you would a normal Javascript function.

Use this to call the function within your Parse.job:

```
updateTopsThree(topThreeObjects);
```

Define function:

```
function updateTopsThree(topObjects) {

  var tops = Parse.Object.extend("testJS");
  var query = new Parse.Query(tops);

    query.get(ObjIDs.topsThreeID(), {
        success: function(topsThree) {

            topsThree.set("topsThree", topObjects);
            topsThree.save();

           response.success(topsThree);
        },
         error: function(object, error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but finally I´ve solved my problem as follows: I´ve created a cloud function like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setLikesInDB", function(request, response) {

    var query = new Parse.Query("testJS");

    query.get(ObjIDs.topsLikesID(), {
        success: function(topsThree) {

            topsThree.set("topsLikes", "likes");
            topsThree.save();
            response.success(topsThree)
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

And then into my Parse.Cloud.Job I´ve called a cloud function like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('setLikesInDB', {obj : listTops}, {
    success: function(result) {
        response.success(result);   
    },
    error: function(error) {
           response.error('some error')
    }
});
```

This way works fine.
I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Can parse cloud code be used to load urls headless? Like CasperJS?